# PHP scan directory with a search string

Tags: php

Is there any way i can search a files array to match a certain string?

So i have a directory with images inside and i put them in a variable 
like so

```
$images = scandir('directory goes here');
```

now i want to search that images array for images with a certain name. 
Like for example all images with a name starting with 'cars_hatchback'.

I've tried using the glob function but it seems i'm coming up short.

Is there any way to accomplish this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at the php's `glob()` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function.

For example, if you have folder structure like this:

```
folder
    |----- autopass2.jpg
    |----- autopass3.png
    |----- auto_pass2.jpg
    |----- otherfile.xml
```

Now just use `glob` function with asterisk:

```
$result = glob('folder/autopass*');
```

And result is:

```
array
(
    0 => 'folder/autopass2.jpg'
    1 => 'folder/autopass3.png'
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much this explained it very well, i was just using the glob function like an idiot it seems.

Answer (score 2):

Use preg_grep to search an array with a pattern:

```
$images = scandir('directory goes here');
$result = preg_grep ("/^cars_hatchback.*/", $images);
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php

Answer (score 1):

[`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) can be used to find filenames starting with a specific string by using an asterisk as a wildcard:

**scandir('cars');**

```
Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => cars_convertible1.jpg
    [3] => cars_hatchback1.jpg
    [4] => cars_hatchback2.jpg
)
```

**glob('cars/cars_hatchback*');**

```
Array
(
    [0] => cars/cars_hatchback1.jpg
    [1] => cars/cars_hatchback2.jpg
)
```